# how to display random ads each time the page is refreshed using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a banner ad on my site, using an asp.net Image control. I want to display a new ad every time the page is refreshed.

Comment: @André Pena - Don't worry. I did.

Comment: But how to do it ? i want each time the page refreshes new ad will display ...

Comment: Use a session key as counter that change per view per user.

Answer (score 4):

### Use Adrotator control:

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/293/adrotator/